# Change is not made onclick event on the data loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, onclick

This is the code to load data dynamically from a php file :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
            function loading_show(){
                $('#loading').html("<img src='demo/img/ajax-loader.gif'/>").fadeIn('fast');
            }
            function loading_hide(){
                $('#loading').fadeOut('fast');
            }                
            function loadData(page){
                loading_show();                    
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "pagination/load_data.php",
                    data: "page="+page,
                    success: function(msg)
                    {
                        $("#container2").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {
                            loading_hide();
                            $("#container2").html(msg);
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
            loadData(1);  // For first time page load default results
            $('#container2 .pagination li.active').live('click',function(){
                var page = $(this).attr('p');
                loadData(page);

            });           
            $('#go_btn').live('click',function(){
                var page = parseInt($('.goto').val());
                var no_of_pages = parseInt($('.total').attr('a'));
                if(page != 0 && page <= no_of_pages){
                    loadData(page);
                }else{
                    alert('Enter a PAGE between 1 and '+no_of_pages);
                    $('.goto').val("").focus();
                    return false;
                }

            }); });
```

This code is running successfully and the output is given. Now i want to add an `onclick` event on the data loaded dynamically and code for this is :

```
function  favourites(gymusernamefav){
                         $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");     
                $.ajax
                ({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "http://fvilla.in/markfavourite.php",
                    data: 'gymusernamefav='+ gymusernamefav,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#container2").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings)
                        {

                            $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");
                        });
                    }
                });


            }


 $('#container2 .shortlisted').live('click',function(){
                var gymusernamefav =  $(this).attr("id");
                favourites(gymusernamefav);
                return false;
            });
```

This code is also running successfully but the change is not made in

```
$("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");
```

After `onClick` no change is made into the class `.shortlisted` ( Change is only made for some seconds and after that the old text is seen)  But the ajax part is running successfully and the query is also executed.

Apreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

> **Delegated events** have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers.

You should use event delegation **[on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)** instead of  deprecated method **[live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)** when you deal with fresh DOM (added dynamically by js) :

```
$('body').on('click','#container2 .shortlisted', function(){
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: hi @zakaria still it's not working all queries are executed but the change is not made permanent it is changes for small time then it comes to it's original state after some time : $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello"); // this part is not making the changes permanently

Comment: What you means by _still it's not working_?? i can see that it change the text for a while, that means the click work now and that what you want refering to your OP, and you get another problem now that is not described in OP.

Comment: i mentioned in OP that the change should be made permanent not for some time. This is the real problem that i mentioned otherwise the query is executed successfully

Comment: From the first look in your code i can see that you have several errors (you don't respect the uniqueness of ids and you place `style`, `script` tags in wrong places..) try to fix those fails and your code should work like expected (and you should be familiar with thanks words cause people here love help and they deserve those words).

Comment: :( It's not about me, i have already posted more than 500 answer and i love helping others, it's about you, you have posted 4 questions and i can't find any positive comment or thankful word in almost 9 answers (this is not working, still it's not working ..), consider to valorize
people who trying to help you, good luck, happy coding.

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this**

```
$(document).delegate("#container2 .shortlisted", "click", function() {
  var gymusernamefav = $(this).attr("id");
  favourites(gymusernamefav);
  return false;
});
```

The [delegate()](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) method attaches one or more event handlers for specified elements that are children of selected elements, and specifies a function to run when the events occur.
**Event handlers attached using the delegate() method will work for both current and FUTURE elements (like a new element created by a script)**.

As of jQuery version 1.7, the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers for selected elements.

**As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated**. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live().

Comment: hi @rino still it's not working all queries are executed but the change is not made permanent it is changes for small time then it comes to it's original state after some time :                                             $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");  // this part is not making the changes permanently

Comment: hi @rino no errors are there this statement after execution doesn't make permanent change to the text present in "shortlisted " class  $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");

Comment: @AnkitSingh $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");  is seen in more than one place. Which is the actual position?

Comment: this is the actual one : function  favourites(gymusernamefav){
                         $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello");

Comment: you can check out the problem here : http://fvilla.in/gymspa Click on the heart button to see the problem

Comment: @AnkitSingh Ok... One more thing. Try to remove that ajaxComplete thing. Just keep $("#container2 .shortlisted").html("hello"); inside sucess

Comment: @AnkitSingh I am getting an error on clicking. The error is Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: can u help me with that !! it will be really healpful

Comment: @AnkitSingh I have no proper access to code.  So I am not able to do it. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

For newly created elements you can use:

```
$(document).on('click', '#container2 .shortlisted', function(){
 ..............   your code  .......
});
```

In previous jQuery version (1.7) you could use the [live()](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Try to change your selector from:

```
$("#container2 .shortlisted")
```

To:

```
$("#container2.shortlisted")
```

No spaces between the two elements in the selector otherwise you are looking for children of container2 with class shortlisted.

Answer (score 0):

Use event delegation for dynamically loaded and generated elements:

```
$(document).on('click','#container2 .shortlisted', function(){
       favourites($(this).attr("id"));
       return false;
 });
```